# How do I easily store user account details?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am posting this as I am unsure the exact technology and approach to investigates further.

I wish to build a simple website:

1) User logs in with username and password.

2) User saves simple page that contains inputs taken from a form they have filled in.

3) User logs out, but all data is kept on server.

4) User logs in again and can see everything stored against their account.

This must be really simple but without much development knowledge I am a little stuck on where to go next.

I know a little bit of the following - HTML/CSS/Javascript/PHP/MySQL

Therefore I was thinking of this approach:

1) User account based off php/mysql script.

2) User inputs into simple page via html/php forms. Added javascript for effect.

3) All form inputs recorded in mysql database.

On the mysql database - how should this be structured?

1) User Account Table:
Username | Email | Last_Login

2) Simple Form Table:
Username | Form_Field1  | Form_Field2 | Form....

Is there a better way to store individual user information - all in one table or an individual table per user?

As coding is not my strength, are there prepacked scripts etc that I can leverage. I was looking at combining an available back end with a Twitter Boostrap front end.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a more efficient way of storing that data;

Your *users* have to have the following columns:

- **id** - an integer with an AUTO_INCREMENT option checked, PRIMARY_KEY - unique id of the ***user***
- **username**
- **email**
- **password**
- **last_login**

Your *forms* table should be structured like this:

- **id** - an integer with an AUTO_INCREMENT option checked, PRIMARY_KEY - unique id of the recored
- **user_id** - Id of the user who filled/posted the form
- **field1**
- **field2**

Comment: Or maybe even change the `forms` table to contain `id`, `user_id`, `fieldname`, `value`. Gives you more flexibility in adding fields in the future.

Comment: No it doesn't. It is a wrong approach. If you are going to do that you would need a separate table. What you have to care the most is repeating data as less as possible!

Comment: I would say it definitely depends on the structure of the projects. Was just adding a further alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine; the only thing I would say is that don't think about going in the direction where you store each user's information in a separate table. The structure you outlined on your question is fine ie: have a user table with username, passwd, last_login, etc and another table for the other "fields", as you call them. When you get the data from this other table, make sure that you include the username as the *key* that connects both tables. Make sure you declare *username* in both tables as a unique key.

Comment: This is obviously wrong approach because you have repeating data - username is usually a string about 10-30 characters long. This surely isn't as efficient as if you have just a user_id!

Answer (score 0):

Creating 1 table for each user will be make your database so complicated..

You can create 3 tables like this::--

1) table_user with fields:--  id, name, account_details_id[foreign key]

2) table_account_details:-- id, username, password, email, last_login

3) table_form:-- id, form_field, user_id[foreign key]

Comment: This is valuable if you want to have some crazy amount of personal information, otherwise it will slow down queries for acquiring that data.